# How to select all textarea boxes within a given div in JQuery? (To disable/require all)

Tags: jquery, forms, textarea

I have a project that shows a DIV within a form when a checkbox is selected, and within that DIV is a a script that could infinitely add text areas.

What I want is if a a bajillion of these text areas are created, I want to disable all of them from being submitted with the form, as well as make them not required if the over arching checkbox is deselected.

Edit: The reason I am specific about the textareas within a given DIV is because I have text areas elsewhere on the form!

So, how would I select all of the text boxes within a given DIV?  Or, by name? (all of them on a given class (since they're all a part of the needb1_3[]array)).  I've found some code/threads/answers to select input boxes, radios, checkboxes, but never text areas.

Thanks for any help in advance.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmdx/rNqwc/1/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input id="needb1-3customcheck" type="checkbox" class="schedb1checkboxes[]" data-     select="#needb1-3custom">Need Custom?
</div>
<div id="needb1-3custom" style="display:none; padding-left:40px;">
    <div id="customb1_3" style="padding-left:40px;">
        <textarea id="needb1_3_1" placeholder="Six Foot Utility..." name="needb1_3[]" required>
        </textarea>
    </div><!-- Ending Custom Div -->
    <div style="padding-left:40px;"><a id="add_b1_3" href="#"><span>Add Exception</span></a></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var b1_3customcounter = 1;
$(function () {
    $('a#add_b1_3').click(function () {
    b1_3customcounter += 1;
        $('#customb1_3').append(
        '<div><textarea id="need_b1_3_' + b1_3customcounter + '" placeholder="Six Foot Utility..." name="needb1_3[]' + '" required></textarea><a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a></div>');                                 
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
var $this = $(this);
$(this).closest('div').remove();
event.preventDefault();
});

$('#needb1-3customcheck').click(function(){
    var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('data-select');                    

    $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
      if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
                    //Do this while the section is hidden
        $('#needb1_3_1').prop('required', false);
}else{
        //Do this while the section is visible
        $('#needb1_3_1').prop('required', true);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: _I've found some code/threads/answers to select input boxes, radios, checkboxes, but never text areas._ What makes you think the method is any different for text areas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the textareas based on their element name not classes or an id.

Try:

```
$('#form textarea').prop('disabled', true);
```

This will work for the other ones such as `select` and `input`.

So to disable all textareas within your div `#needb1-3custom` try:

```
$('#needb1-3custom textarea').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant by name instead of class, edited thread.

Also edited thread to mention I have text areas elsewhere on the form, would this effect them as well?

Comment: Try it out, you can select these elements as shown above, and you can limit the selection of these elements to a scope (eg div) such as `.form1` or `#form1`.

Comment: This was way too simple (especially with the clarification).  I was going about this in my few stabs at this trying to select it by input[] and a few other ways and it never worked.  Complete brain fart and simple.  Thanks

Comment: Happens to everyone! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following :

```
 $('#customb1_3 textarea').attr('disabled',true);
```

Here `customb1_3` is textarea container div Id.